# Adjust notification sound volume on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-audiomanager

Is there any way to adjust notification sound volume without adjusting media / call volume?

I want to set notification volume to the max level while keeping current media / call volume level.

Thanks in advance!

Currently using Java on Android Studio

Comment: I think no. You must respect user settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can adjust notification sound alone by calling [AudioManager.setStreamVolume](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/AudioManager#setstreamvolume)

Example:

```
val audioManager = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
val notificationMaxVol = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION) 
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, notificationMaxVol, 0)
```

**Note**: You must get **Do Not disturb access** for your app before calling the above method.